# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scaling'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-2.x, pyevolve

I am trying to install pyevolve module in Windows CMD.

I tried 3 ways to install it.

1. `pip install pyevolve`
2. `easy_install pyevolve`
3. `cd C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/`

   `python setup.py install`

The result is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Scaling'
```

I look through `C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/`, and I find there is a document named `Scaling.py`. However, it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

In short: the code is old and obviously intended for Python 2, but you seem trying it with Python 3. Use Python 2 for `pyevolve`.

The problem is the `setup.py` imports `pyevolve` and `pyevolve.__init__` imports `pyevolve.Consts` and `pyevolve.Consts` imports `Scaling`. In Python 2 that import works because Py 2 allows relative import. But in Python 3 default import is absolute and there is no global module `Scaling`.

Comment: thank you for your help. That is to say, If I want to use pyevolve, I must import by Python 2? However, if there is a possibility that I could import it by Python 3?

Comment: thank you for your help again. I think I have solved this problem.

Comment: thank you for your help again. I think I have solved this problem. /n step 1 In WinDos type: python install future. /n step 2 https://github.com/BubaVV/Pyevolve I download this module above net, and WinDos cd C:\XXXX\XXXX\ /n python setup.py install. /n then I finished.

Comment: I don't know how do you type "enter" when answer question, I use "/n" to replace the key "enter".